# True or False: Is there a New He-Man and the Masters of the Universe film coming?

Tags: movie, he-man, masters-of-the-universe

I've been hearing rumors of this for the last *year,* and frankly I just want some **factual** information.

Does anybody know anything?

What "version" of the MOTU story are they going to use (Toy Line, Cartoon 83, Cartoon 2002, one of the comic book series. something original?)

Any cast and crew officially assigned?

Possible release date?

Comment: I'm really not sure if our future works policy dictates closing this question or not

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe Sorry; not trying to be a pain. There's just a lot of confusing information, so I was looking for anything **concrete** to go on, and I know _someone_ in here likely has confirmed facts.

Comment: There was also a live action movie done in I think it was the late 80s or early 90s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently yes seeing the main character has been cast and even an release date is given.

> Sony Pictures and Mattel have tapped the directing duo of Aaron and
> Adam Nee to helm the He-Man movie “Masters of the Universe,” sources
> tell Variety.
>
> <sub><sup>[‘Masters of the Universe’: Nee Brothers to Direct He-Man Movie (EXCLUSIVE)](https://variety.com/2018/film/news/he-man-movie-director-masters-of-the-universe-1202763492/)</sup></sub>

and

> Writers Art Marcum & Matt Holloway are in final talks to write the new
> draft of Masters of the Universe, which Adam Aaron Nee will direct.

https://deadline.com/2019/01/art-marcum-matt-holloway-writing-new-draft-of-sony-mattel-films-masters-of-the-universe-1202533815/

> Noah Centineo is in talks to play the lead role of He-Man in Sony
> Pictures and Mattel Films “Masters of the Universe,” an individual
> with knowledge of the project exclusively tells TheWrap.
>
> Aaron and Adam Nee are set to direct from a script rewritten by “Iron
> Man” screenwriters Matt Holloway and Art Marcum.  The Nee Brothers
> also have screenwriting credit.

https://www.thewrap.com/noah-centineo-he-man-masters-of-the-universe/

> Noah Centineo couldn't be more thrilled for his role in the upcoming
> remake of Masters of the Universe.

https://www.msn.com/en-ca/entertainment/movies/noah-centineo-confirms-hes-playing-he-man-in-masters-of-the-universe-i-am-very-excited/ar-AAAINqF?li=AAggNb9

> Sony Pictures and Mattel Films have set a March 5, 2021, release date
> for Masters of the Universe, the latest film adaptation of a Mattel
> toy line.

https://deadline.com/2019/05/masters-of-the-universe-release-date-noah-centenio-1202616904/

http://thathashtagshow.com/2018/05/masters-of-the-universe/

http://geeksoncoffee.com/masters-of-the-universe/

Comment: There's a lot of links here but if they go dead, your answer becomes effectively useless. Why not copy out some of the relevant detail into your answer?

Comment: @Valorum Edited

Comment: Much better. You might want to convert the links into in-line links to make it a little less busy/messy. I've done the first to show the format I prefer to use but you can go for your own style.

Comment: @Valorum how is that done?